# How can I share my Java Applet?

Tags: java, applet, share

Have just finished programming my first Java Applet. How can I share this with my friends without them using eclipse on my computer?

I have 12 classes in eclipse. I have seen some examples of people using HTML to embed their applet in a website, but

A) I have only found examples with only one class.

B) I tried following this method: http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/37
but when I click on the html file, it just opens the html code in my browser, not the applet.

This is the HTML file that I made

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
World Cup Game
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>World Cup Game</h2>
<applet
codebase=“https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcojvh8tm2mukzn”
archive = “WorldCup.jar”
width = 800 height = 600>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't mind whether I share it embedded on a web page or if I send them an executable jar file or whatever, but does anyone know how I can share my hard work!? Thanks :)
(Apparently executable jar file isn't an option with applets though...)

Comment: you html is not valid because of those weird quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is an option:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>My Applet Page</html>
</head>

<body>
<applet code="ClassFile.class" archive="YourJar.jar" width="400px" height="400px">
Java is not installed on your machine or your browser does not allowed Java Applet to run<br /><br />Get the latest Java technology at <a href="http://www.java.com/">http://www.java.com/</a>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

But I would not use that. Servlets are much better idea. Applets are client side thing if you do something that do not have to be processed on back-end why not  but I did not see any applets for couple of years...

If you dont see your applet then probably you have `public static void main(String[] args)` instead of `public void init()` that also could make you problems

Answer (score -1):

**The basic Problem about applets are that they need jvm oriented browsers to run.**
due to this reason applets(java) failed. today servlets are considered. **you would need eclipse or any jvm for your browser to run..**

Comment: You need a JVM to run Java Applications and the Java Plugin to run applets in your browser. Your answer is a bit shaky.

Comment: @Kayaman java oriented browsers is the answer to use applets.